Cloth physics not falling
I want the selected plane to fall down but it wouldn't.
I made sure gravity is 1 and it is subdivided and everything seems to be right just like the tutorial.I am very confused 

Please don't take photos of your computer screen. It makes it difficult to see the settings with the screen reflections. Use Blender's built-in Window > Save Screenshot menu and edit the image that it produces into your question.

Sorry, but without seeing all your settings or even better having the file, it is really hard to tell what is wrong. "Everything seems to be right just like the tutorial" - obviously it's not, otherwise it should work like in the tutorial. But you didn't tell us which and even if we would not know where you made a mistake. Usually the best solution would be to start the tutorial again and make sure you follow it tthoroughly and pay close attention to the steps shown there.

one reason could be duplicated vertices. Select all verts in Edit mode and press key M > Merge by Distance. In the status bar, you should see whether there were duplicate vertices that are now merged.
